# Containers or components for conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's best practise when it comes to rendering error, loading or empty state?

Is it better to have the container control the rendering, or have the component that it essentially refers to control this?

e.g

```
render() {
    const {
       loading,
       error,
       items 
    } = this.state;

    return (
       <div>
          {
             loading &&
             <Loading />
          }
          {
             error &&
             <Error />
          }
          etc...
```

or

```
const ItemList = ({ items, loading, error }) => {
    if (loading) {
       return <Loading />
    }
    etc...
```

All opinions welcome/appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine and are "officially correct" according to the docs. [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

However, in your example I personally think your second example is more readable. First you take care of the special cases (error and loading) then the "happy path". It's quick and easy to read!

Comment: I had completely forgotten about this page even though i've visited it before - so this was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think we should make as much components as possible. It make code clearly, and components more functional.

In your case, logic should be in base component. I think, your component  should be responsible just for his own view. And it should not be aware of the logic with which it should be displayed.